# matlab ARX parameter

Tags: matlab, input

I want to use ARX. X is a 1000X13 matrix (1000 sample with 13 features). I want to see the relationship of for example 1st and 2nd column of X. I don't know how to make input parameters right. What should be the size of [na nb nk] for my regression problem. Matlab documentation doesn't have much detail.

Here is my code:

```
data = iddata(X(:,1),[],1); %I have to make iddata object first.

Y = arx(data,[ [ones(size(X(:,1),2),size(X(:,1),2))]  [ones(size(X(:,2),1),size(X(:,1),1))] [ones(size(X(:,1),2),size(X(:,1),1))] ])
```

Error is:

> Error using horzcat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

---

I tried to change the dimensions of [na nb nk], but every time, I got an error like:

- `Y = arx(data,[ [ones(size(X(:,1),2),size(X(:,1),2))] 1 [ones(size(X(:,1),2),size(X(:,1),1))] ])`

  > Invalid ARX orders. Note that continuous-time ARX models are not supported.
- `Y = arx(data,[ 1  1 1])`

  > Error using arx (line 77)
  >   The model orders must be compatible with the input and output dimensions of the estimation data.

Comment: `arx` requires that you know the number of poles `na` the number of zeroes `nb` and the number of delays `nk` before hand.  You have to know some things about your system before you use this and determine your model.  What is this data of?  Do you know **anything** about the data you collected?  You also need to create an `iddata` object that encapsulates **both the input and output**.  As such, you would need to do `data = iddata(X(:,1), X(:,2), 1);`.  The first param is the output while the second is the input. I don't know what order you want this in.

Comment: I am not familiar with poles, zeroes, and delay.. I want to see if input and output have any relationship in terms of the regression equation: output can be estimated using its historical value and also using historical value of input.I saw some people use ARX for this reason in the literature. Example: http://www.nec-labs.com/~haifeng/mypubs/jiang-tkde-07.pdf

Comment: Seems this question died......